# How to generate a collection of all widgets that have a Text property in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Basic 2010 Express and would like to be able to form a collection of all widgets that have a Text property associated with them for each Form that I have in my project. How can this be programmed in VB within my project? The reason behind this is to be able to translate the contents of the Text to different languages, when required by the user.

Comment: Widgets? What you mean exactly? What format are you using (WPF, winforms, ASP...)?

Comment: you could write a component which loops thru the controls and adds the ones which have a .Text property to a collection(of control).  Not all .Text is the same though: that on a ListView is different than a TextBox which are both different from a Label.  in the end you are looking at localization which does not do it this way.

Comment: For example, I have a pull-down menu item that contains a text field. I would like to be able to collect all such pull-downs and buttons and ... that contain a text field (i.e. have a text property). I have done this for controls (a collection is defined for controls); but, my question is about any component (that I called a widget) that contains a text field.

Comment: I am working with a Visual Basic 2010 Express project that contains windows forms, an About form and a Splash form.